# webpack-dev-server v4 is missing compilation log output

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I recently migrated a project from webpack-cli v2 to v4 and webpack-dev-server from v3 to v4. This is in preparation to further migrate to v5 at a later point in time.

I followed the [webpack-dev-server v4 migration](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md) as well as the [v1 to v2/3 webpack migration](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#root), and the [v3 to v4 webpack migration](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4/).

Everything is working, with one exception.

Using webpack-dev-server with hots enabled, previously the output would say

```
[wmd]: Compiling...
...
[wmd]: Compiled successfully
```

Or some times it would say

```
[wmd]: Compiled with warnings.
```

or with errors, as appropriate.

This would happen when files were changed. This output is missing and I can't figure out how to get it back, it wasn't configured to have it before, it was the default. How do I get this output to come back? I can't see anything about this in the migration guides or changelogs.

I tried configuring:

```
devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
        stats: {
            preset: 'minimal',
            log: 'info',
        },
    },
}
```

But the output is still missing the compiling start/end, where is this now configured? Which config options specifically?

Answer (score 0):

The [reporter in webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/blob/v3.7.3/lib/reporter.js) was removed. You can see how they use it [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/blob/v3.7.3/lib/context.js).

Based on this, I wrote my own plugin to use when using `webpack serve` and hot reloading (HMR).

The plugin hooks into the `beforeCompile` and `afterEmit` webpack hooks to simply log "Compiling..." and "Compiling finished." so that there is some obvious change on the terminal to know it actually did recompile.